# How to setup Gruntfile with html2js in my Yeoman project?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, ng-html2js

I guess the title is quite trivial. I have been develeoping with AngularJS for a while and used grunt only for some projects and it's only with yeoman. So I can say that I'm quite new to grunt.

I have tried to follow the path in [grunt-html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) page and managed to create `templates.js` with the following code:

```
html2js: {
            options: {

            },
            main: {
                src: ['app/views/**/*.html'],
                dest: 'dist/tmp/templates.js'
            }
        }, //...
```

Then below:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin',
        'html2js' 
    ]);
```

**What I try to do is wiring this file to the** `index.html` **and then remove the html files in the "views" folder.**

Since this is a test project, file structure is pretty much same with a new yeoman project.
Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: What you are saying sounds right to me, what issue are you having?

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't wire the produced js file to index.html and remove the the html files in "dist" folder...

Comment: Did you add the module 'templates-main' as a dependency of your main app?

Comment: Sure I did, but then it stopped compiling and throws error during grunt compile...

Comment: you are using 'usemin'. Please post your index.html relevant part with usemin markup

Comment: It's standard yeoman structure except the snippets I've wrote in the question...